# How to tie name to _parameter1, parameter2 to be name_parameter1 in R function?

Tags: r, function

I have function test where I have argument name. I want to "add" name to a column plus the parameter as shown here:

```
test <- function(name, dataframe) {
        dataframe$name_parameter1 = 5
        dataframe$name_parameter2 = 4
}
```

What is the way to combine name with _parameter1 _parameter2 etc?
To make it name_parameter1 etc.

(In R)

Comment: @LAP But if I want to use if? If dataframe$name_param1 == 2 I will do it using:
if (dataframe[, paste(name, "param1", sep = " "] == 2) {
t = 3
} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, you can use different ways to call values in a dataframe. You chose one by using `$` to call a column within the dataframe.

A different way that can handle string expressions is using `[row, column]`, where `column` can either be a numeric position of the column within the dataframe, or the column name as a string.

Therefore, instead of using `dataframe$name_parameter1 = 5`, you can use `dataframe[, "name_parameter1"] = 5`. And the column name can then be generated using `paste()`, ergo `dataframe[, paste(name, "parameter1", sep = "_")]`, which handles your function input `name` (as long as it is a string).

`[row, column]` works with `if` or `ifelse()`, so `dataframe[, paste(name, "parameter1", sep = "_")] == 4` as an `if`-condition is perfectly valid.